# Web service or library to generate colored boxes with first letter of user's name (like in Gmail Android/iPhone) app

Tags: gravatar

Does anyone know if such a thing exists. It would be a great addition to Gravatar!

This is what I'm referring to:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks,
Graeme